# @ComponentScan not detecting beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I have the following multi-project structure:

```
-ParentProject
   -project1
     -src
       -package1
           -package1.1
           -package1.2
        Scan.java
        Main.java
   -src
       -package2
           -package2.1
           -package2.2
```

In Scan.java I have the following code snippet:

```
      final ActionForSimulatorComponent annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(bean.getClass(), ActionForSimulatorComponent.class);
```

Effectively what I want to do is find all beans with @ActionForSimulatorComponent annotation. But I only find the beans that are present in package1, and not in package2. Fair enough, so I have tried the following in my Main.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(value = {"package1", "package2"}, nameGenerator = FullClassBeanNameGenerator.class)
public class Main extends Scan
```

That only returned beans from package1, but nothing from package2. I suspect I have the wrong project structure, I understand that I need to put my main class into a parent package and then everything will get scanned downwards without problems. But what is happening is that I have two different projects, and I am including project1 into the parentProject as a source tree.

Is it even possible for Spring to work with such a structure? If so, what am I doing wrong?

**Can I scan for beans in the parent project of the sub-project where I have the Main class?**

Comment: Are you using maven? If so perhaps you could share snippets from your pom.xml files?